# Create a GUI application directly with GCC, remove console

Tags: winapi, user-interface, gcc

I decided to create applications direct with Notepad + GCC Compiler (and the entire Mingw environment).

Well I started by creating a simple Win32 application (a simple window). The file is only 4 Kb (which, with an IDE like C:B or VS is about 8 kb.

Anyway, my problem is that the window is displayed but also a window console. Well, I don't want the console to appear but only the GUI window. I think this is achieved by creating manifest files or something like that, of which I don't know much about, as this is the first time I am trying this. How do I tell GCC that it shouldn't create a console window - just a GUI window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an executable that targets the GUI subsystem rather than the console subsystem. In the MS tools the normal way to indicate that is to use a different form of main function:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, 
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                   LPSTR lpszArgument, 
                   int nCmdShow)
```

I believe that mingw supports the same convention.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that apart from a GUI window, a console window was appearing. -mwindows was the trick.

Comment: This also works. Two different ways to make mingw target the GUI subsystem rather than the console subsystem. http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, **-mwindows** can solve the problem. And I found another option, passing **-Wl,--subsystem,windows** when using gcc to compile. Both of them are OK.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. For anyone having the same question: use -`mwindows` in your command line, when compiling the code with GCC. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's the other way of making mingw target the GUI subsystem.