# How can I do the FreeConsole() but faster on c++

Tags: c++, windows, console

I would very much like to know how I would be able to do the same function as [`FreeConsole()` Windows API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) but faster.

The `FreeConsole()` does hide the console, but still, the console window flashes open before it's hidden. I would like to have the console not open at all if it is possible. thank you.

*update based on comments*

My OS is Windows. I use the gcc compiler with the `windows.h` header and am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: That's no standard c++ function. What's your OS, framework?

Comment: Please update your post with the source code you are using with `FreeConsole()` to show us how you are doing the it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its Windows API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole

Comment: @RichardChambers I know that of course, OP should mention that, or tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Please add more information, like your environment, to the question!

Comment: Since this is a Windows API call, more than likely the functionality is part of the Windows operating system hence not something you could do yourself. I would suggest that rather than creating a console application which creates a console as a part of starting up, you create a graphical application instead. You have much more control over windows that are created and displayed with a graphical application.

Comment: @RichardChambers thank you for the comment. I thought that graphical applications had a console behind the main window, same as the one FreeConsole() hides? also, I am a beginner and have no idea how to make a graphic application.

Comment: @HalHana I use Visual Studio Community Edition and not gcc with Visual Code so I'm not sure how a graphical UI is done with your particular development environment. With Visual Studio it is a matter of starting a new project and selecting a Windows graphical application template. A graphical UI app uses a different link library and entry point than does a console app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474504/compiling-a-win32-gui-app-without-a-console-using-mingw-and-eclipse and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746496/create-a-gui-application-directly-with-gcc-remove-console

Comment: @richardchambers thanks for the advice! I take it that there is nothing that can hide the console in the first place? I'll definitely look into graphical UI apps using the links that you mentioned!! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Microsoft documentation About Consoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console) there is this text:

> The system creates a new console when it starts a console process, a
> character-mode process whose entry point is the main function. For
> example, the system creates a new console when it starts the command
> processor cmd.exe. When the command processor starts a new console
> process, the user can specify whether the system creates a new console
> for the new process or whether it inherits the command processor's
> console.

What the documentation indicates is that in order to not have a console displayed, you will need to create an executable that is not a console application.

#### Second and better answer

After thinking about this more I realized that my first answer could be simplified. Rather than a Windows GUI application that starts a non-console process, you could instead write a Windows GUI application that is the non-console application.

I think that the two things that control this are: (1) C++ source code and the main entry point specified and (2) the **/SUBSYSTEM** linker option which determines the executable environment and entry point the linker uses for the application.

See this Microsoft article, [/SUBSYSTEM (Specify Subsystem)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-160) for details about the /SUBSYSTEM linker directive.

> The /SUBSYSTEM option specifies the environment for the executable.
>
> The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point
> function) that the linker will select.

Using Visual Studio 2019, I created a Windows desktop application which I then cut down, eliminating all the Windows GUI application source code and keeping only the `wWinMain()` entry point. Then I modified this application to use standard C++ libraries to create a simple text file and exit to demonstrate that this works.

I ended up with the following source code for a C++ test application.

```
// cmndline_non_console.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    std::ofstream myfile;

    myfile.open("test.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.  more\n";
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The solution Properties for the Link is using the **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS**.

[image: screen shot of solution Properties showing linker System options]

#### First answer

This [Microsoft documentation Windows Console and Terminal Ecosystem Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) describes the history of Windows console and changes to the newer psuedo-console and Virtual Terminal functionality

Here is a simplified GUI that starts up, starts a child process without a console, and then exits. It uses the `CreateProcess()` Windows API function. See [The Command CreateProcess C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610277/the-command-createprocess-c) and see also [Creating Processes in the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes).

I created the main application by using the Visual Studio 2019 IDE to create a new Windows Desktop GUI application and then made a couple of changes to the generated code. You can probably cut out more of this. There is a dependency on a couple of standard generated files: `framework.h`, `Resource.h`, and `targetver.h`. The header file `startconsoleless.h` just contains the include directive for `Resource.h`.

- the `InitInstance()` function returns `FALSE` so that the application exits
- the `InitInstance()` function uses the `CActualApp` class to create a new process without a console
- the `About` dialog processing was deleted as it is unused

This example uses a hard coded command line to indicate the executable to be launched. The use of an array of `wchar_t` characters is needed or the `CreateProcess()` function will trigger an exception per the SO post referred to.

File startconsoless.cpp

```
// startconsoleless.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "startconsoleless.h"
#include "CActualApp.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

CActualApp myApp;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_STARTCONSOLELESS, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_STARTCONSOLELESS));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_STARTCONSOLELESS));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_STARTCONSOLELESS);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   // Comment out following code in order to not show the created window.

   // ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   // UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   // At this point we can now have our main thread of this process
   // start another thread to do the work we want to do

   // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610277/the-command-createprocess-c

   wchar_t appLine[] = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
   myApp.StartAnApp(appLine);

   // return FALSE so that this Windows GUI app will exit after
   // starting the child process.
   return FALSE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is a very simple class the above uses to start up an application.

File CAcutalApp.h

```
#pragma once
class CActualApp
{
public:
    CActualApp() {}
    ~CActualApp() {}

    int StartAnApp(wchar_t * pAppComndLine);
};
```

File CActualApp.cpp

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "CActualApp.h"

int CActualApp::StartAnApp(wchar_t * pAppComndLine)
{
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610277/the-command-createprocess-c

    int  retStatus = 0;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };

    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    BOOL apStart = CreateProcess(NULL, pAppComndLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    if (!apStart)
    {
        // create process failed
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        
        retStatus = errorCode;
    }
    else {
        // close process and thread handles
        CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
    }

    return retStatus;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and edit on the question! It's late here, so I'll try out the code tomorrow. Again, thanks!

Comment: @HalHana let me know how it works for you. My testing was with Visual Studio 2019 and it seemed to work fine. The idea would be to modify the path in the call to `StartAnApp()` to the actual application you want to start. It's a command line so you should be able to add arguments as well as the executable path in the string.

Comment: It worked! thanks. sorry it took some time to respond. It's been a busy week...

Comment: There are ramifications to changing a Console app to a Windows app, including (unnecessarily) increasing the memory footprint during runtime.
Question: Why not just write the code as a Windows Service? That would follow best practices -and- allows more fine grained control over the privileges under which it runs.

Comment: @StacyDudovitz I have a simple console application to test a library written in C++. I changed it from subsystem CONSOLE to subsystem WINDOWS, added an include windows.h, and added the WinMain() function. A release build of both the CONSOLE and the WINDOWS versions yield the same size of .exe and when run they loaded the same .dlls so I'm wondering where you found that the memory footprint is greater with subsystem WINDOWS. The posted question doesn't say anything about the intended use is a Windows Service.